# Стили для элементов с несколькими классами

Tags: html, css

Всем привет!

Есть html-код:

```
<div class="one">бла-бла-бла</div>
<div class="one">бла-бла-бла</div>
<div class="one">бла-бла-бла</div>
<div class="one">бла-бла-бла</div>
<div class="one two">тра-та-та</div>
<div class="one two">тра-та-та</div>
<div class="one two">тра-та-та</div>
<div class="one two">тра-та-та</div>
```

Задача: скрыть на мобильных устройствах "бла-бла-бла".

Как собственно можно скрыть только элементы с классом "one"?

Если сделаю

```
.one {
    dislpay: none;
}
```

, то исчезнут и "тра-та-та", а нужно чтобы они остались. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте `:not()` ([документация](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/:not)):

```css
.one:not(.two) {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">бла-бла-бла</div>
<div class="one">бла-бла-бла</div>
<div class="one">бла-бла-бла</div>
<div class="one">бла-бла-бла</div>
<div class="one two">тра-та-та</div>
<div class="one two">тра-та-та</div>
<div class="one two">тра-та-та</div>
<div class="one two">тра-та-та</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное! :)

Answer (score 1):

> Как собственно можно скрыть только элементы с классом "one"?

Предложу такой вариант...

```css
[class="one"] {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">бла-бла-бла</div>
<div class="one">бла-бла-бла</div>
<div class="one">бла-бла-бла</div>
<div class="one">бла-бла-бла</div>
<div class="one two">тра-та-та</div>
<div class="one two">тра-та-та</div>
<div class="one two">тра-та-та</div>
<div class="one two">тра-та-та</div>
```

Comment: `[class="one"]` это значит, что див ТОЛЬКО с классом `one` ? //то есть в диве только один класс записан, так?

Comment: @Dev18, именно так.

Comment: а если в диве есть айди(ID), сработает ? `<div class="one" id="someId">бла-бла-бла</div>`

Comment: @Dev18, это селектор атрибута, он распространяется только на указанный атрибут и его значение. Остальные атрибуты могут быть любыми или вообще отсутствовать.